# c++11 object that can be passed as "double (*)[4]"

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdarray

I need to call an function in an external library that has a signature:

```
void fn(double (*values)[4]);
```

but I would like to pass an object like `std::vector<std::array<double, 4>>` and it must be c++11 compliant. How would I call this function?

Comment: Do you really need it to be standard-compliant? `fn((double(*)[4]) my_vec.data())` is technically UB, but is good enough in practice.

Comment: That would be a rather unfortunate signature. What is the size of the array that the function expects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 4>> my_array;
...
// Function call:
fn((double(*)[4]) &my_array[array_index][0]);
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that this would be a `reinterpret_cast<double(*)[4]>(&my_array[0][0])`

Comment: Sorry not sure @Peter, I've never used C++'s casts, I've always used C casts in my code.

Comment: One note: due to flaws in the C++ standard, the above is undefined behavior if the function wants to access more than just the first 4 doubles.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I call this function?

The most clean way to call the function is:

1. Create an array of four doubles.
2. Fill up the data in the array from an appropriate source.
3. Pass the address of the array to the function

---

```
double array[4];

// Fill up the array with data
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
{
   array[i] = ...;
}

fn(&array);
```

---

In order to be able to call the function when you have a `std::vector<std::array<double, 4>>`, you can create couple of wrapper functions.

```
void fn_wrapper(std::array<double, 4>>& in)
{
  double array[4];

  // Fill up the array with data
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
  {
     array[i] = in[i];
  }

  fn(&array);

  // If you fn modified array, and you want to move those modifications
  // back to the std::array ...
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
  {
     in[i] = array[i];
  }
}

void fn_wrapper(std::vector<std::array<double, 4>>& in)
{
   for ( auto& item : in )
   {
      fn_wrapper(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is very unlikely to be the *correct* way to call that function. There is no reason for a function to accept a pointer to an array unless the pointer is meant to point to the first element of a higher-dimensional array. `double[4][4]` is much more likely to be the intended argument type.

Comment: @n.m. Or if they want bounds checked at compile-time